# Spring AMPQ rabbit-template publish confirmation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

i am trying to use RabbitMq with the help of RabbitTemplate(i am using spring boot application) .i am able to do the communication part and it is working fine with me but i have one issue.

**Issue:** how can i get acknowledgement after publishing message? i have not seen any method in **RabbitTemplate**,i need it because i have encountered the problem that some times my messages do not reach the server and  that is a problem for me .

****************EDIT*********************

As Artem Bilan suggested i have implemented but still some how its not working . Please see my code.

```
    public boolean sendMessage() {
    try {
        String jsonMessage = convertMessageToJson(message);
        template.setQueue("test_queue");
        template.setRoutingKey("test_queue");
        template.convertAndSend(null, "test_queue", jsonMessage,
                new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        // template.convertAndSend(jsonMessage + counter.incrementAndGet());
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                TestMessageConfiguration.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**And**

**My bean**

```
    @Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    template.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

    template.setReturnCallback(new ReturnCallback() {
        @Override
        public void returnedMessage(Message message, int replyCode,
                String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey) {
            System.out.println("Received returnedMessage with result {}"
                    + routingKey);
            log.info("Received returnedMessage with result {}", routingKey);

        }
    });

    template.setConfirmCallback(new ConfirmCallback() {
        @Override
        public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack,
                String cause) {
            System.out
                    .println("*************************************************************************************"
                            + ack);
            log.info("Received confirm with result {}", ack);

        }
    });
    template.setMandatory(true);

    return template;
}
```

when i setCallback and ConfirmCallback before sending actual message 
i am getting exception

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel does not support confirms or returns; is the connection factory configured for confirms or returns?
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.addListener(RabbitTemplate.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:540)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:605)
    at com.xx.yy.backend.messaging.MessageSenderTest.sendMessage(MessageSenderTest.java:88)
    at com.xx.yy.backend.messaging.MessageSenderTest.sendMessageTest(MessageSenderTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, pay attention that, actually, `RabbitTemplate` has those options implementing `PublisherCallbackChannel.Listener`.

You can find more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#template-confirms):

> The RabbitTemplate implementation of AmqpTemplate supports Publisher Confirms and Returns.

and so on until:

> Only one ConfirmCallback is supported by a RabbitTemplate.

**UPDATE**

Please, read StackTrace and therefore docs carefully:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel does not support confirms or returns; is the connection factory configured for confirms or returns?

And the answer from the link above:

> 3.2.4 Publisher Confirms and Returns
>
> Confirmed and returned messages are supported by setting the CachingConnectionFactory's publisherConfirms and publisherReturns properties to 'true' respectively.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Could you please see my modified code and provide your feedback because some how its still not working for me .

Comment: While adding listener  i am getting illegalstateexception

Comment: Docs link has been fixed.